# Why is there no column added in a DataGrid object after setting ItemsSource?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

After I set the ItemsSource for a DataGrid object, there is no column - but why?

Example:

```
class Record
{
    string C1 { get; set; }

    public Record(string c1)
    {
        this.C1 = c1;
    }
}

private void BuildDataGrid() {
    var records = new Record[] {new Record("foo")};
    var dataGrid = new DataGrid();
    dataGrid.ItemsSource = records;
    // dataGrid.Columns.Count  delivers  0
}
```

**Update:** Even with `public` accessors for the class and property, the problem remains.

**Update 2:** With `dataGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = true` set before specifying the `ItemsSource` does not help, too.

Surpringsly, when I display the `dataGrid` object, the column will be shown in the window! But the count of the columns (as shown above) remains 0.

Comment: Make the C1 property public (and perhaps also the Record class)?

Comment: Make Sure that the DataGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = True

Comment: @eranotzap thank you, but did not helper either :-(

Comment: Default value for `DataGrid.AutoGenerateColumns` is true anyways.

Comment: 2 things come to mind , 
1) since your ItemsSource does not come from a Property the DataGrid would not know how to generate the column header , (2) you have to specify the binding when you bind to an indexer to be [key] 

in other words specify the columns by hand .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

DataGrid internally `generate columns for all public properties exposed by underlying
 object`.

So you need to make `C1 property public` in class

```
public string C1 { get; set; }
```

---

**Updated for reason of column count set to 0.**

Column count will be 0 unless columns are auto generated. You can check column count once they gets generated by hooking on event `AutoGeneratedColumns`. Column count will be updated only once they get rendered on UI.

```
dataGrid.AutoGeneratedColumns += (s,e) =>
       {
           int count = dataGrid.Columns.Count;
           dataGrid.Columns[0].Header = "New Header Name";
       };
```

Here column count will be 1.

Comment: Thank you, but even with public accessors for the class and the property I will get 0 columns..

Comment: Why are you doing this - `var dataGrid = new DataGrid();`? dataGrid should be declared in XAML.

Comment: My application creates DataGrids dynamically (and different numbers of DataGrids), so there is not one single DataGrid I can define in XAML.

Comment: Have you make sure its added properly as child in window and its the one for which you are binding here?

Comment: @JohnThreepwood You need to add the DataGrid to its parent control. Please see my updated answer

Comment: @VimalCK -He has already added it as mentioned in updated question.

Comment: @JohnThreepwood - I have updated the answer that's why column count is still 0. See updated answer.

Comment: @RohitVats thank you for explaining the behavior. Now I understand the reason. Initially I wanted to access the columns via `dataGrid.Columns` to change the Header titles, but now I have to display the DataGrid first and change it afterwards again? :-(

Comment: Why not change the property name to header name which you want to show for your DataGrid?

Comment: This was my first attempt, too, but unfortunately the header name contains special characters.

Comment: So you can do that in event `AutoGeneratedColumns` which i mentioned in answer. That will work. Check updated answer.

Comment: @RohitVats Thank you very much, worked perfectly! Additional question, if you don't mind: You mentioned creating the DataGrid in XAML and use bindings. Is it possible to go this way even with non-static DataGrid creation (e.g. the application creates a dynamically number of DataGrids choosen by the user)?

Comment: Yeah you can. Create a custom UserControl and resuse it by creating an instance of it at runtime and add as a child of panel (eg. Grid).